# Replace specific strings of exisitng pdf document using PHP

Tags: php, pdf

The situation is we get contents of pdf from another server and pdf is made available to download in the following way.

```
$file = base64_decode ((string) $document->content);
$filename = (!empty($document->FileName)) ? (string) $document->FileName : 'Document';
drupal_add_http_header('Content-Type', 'application/pdf');
drupal_add_http_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename=' . $filename);
echo $file;
exit;
```

Now I want to replace some strings of pdf document from "xyz" to "abc" . I don't know how can I do that. How can I replace some strings in the pdf content? I tried str_replace and it didn't work at all.

Comment: are you writing that pdf originally, or did it come from some other place?  if you are using php to create that pdf, you'll need to replace those strings before pdf creation. if you aren't authoring the pdf, your solution is going to be, likely, non-existent, or at the least, very rare and difficult to implement.

Comment: @WEBjuju, I'm not the author of pdf. contents of pdf come from some other place. I'm trying to use PHP to alter its contents.

Comment: Altering pdf contents is highly non-trivial: e.g. your "simple" replacing one string by another can be pretty difficult. On one hand font information need not contain mappings to Unicode. Thus, you might not even recognise your string to replace. On the other hand the font may be present only as a subset. Thus, you might not even have glyphs for your replacement.